# Highchart Crosshair not touching x axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to increase height of my xAxis crosshair to touch the x axis. Is there a way to achieve this. Below i have attached screen shot and code snippet for the same

```
Highcharts.chart(container, {
   title: {
     text: ""
    },
    xAxis: {
     type: "datetime",
     crosshair: true
    }
}
```

[image]

I tried using it as tooltip option

```
 tooltip: {
        crosshairs: {
            color: 'green',
            width:  2,
            height: 10

        }
    }
```

It takes width but does not take the height options

[Js fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/fc3mxkgz/23/)

Comment: Do you have a live example of this? I'd expect touching the X-axis to be the default behavior.

Comment: @HalvorStrand yes in all the examples i have seen online, this is the case. But in my case crosshair is not touching X- axis. I don't have a live example to share now. I will update

Comment: @HalvorStrand edited the answer and added a js fiddle link

Comment: What's happening here is that the crosshair line does not go below the x-axis baseline. Right now, it's your `offset` attribute that's doing that ... if you removed that, the line goes all the way down as expected. The line also stops if you set `top` on the x-axis as well. Perhaps @HalvorStrand has a styling solution that could help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently the crosshair goes to where the x-axis baseline is expected to be (not accounting for offset), as also described by Mike Zavarello in the comments.

One workaround from my understanding of your situation is to extend Highcharts and instead draw the crosshair from the maximum value of your first y-axis (the one nearest the top) to the bottom of your second y-axis (the one nearest the bottom).

For example ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fc3mxkgz/65/)):

```
(function (H) {
    H.wrap(H.Axis.prototype, 'drawCrosshair', function (proceed, e, point) {
        let old_function = H.Axis.prototype.getPlotLinePath;
        H.Axis.prototype.getPlotLinePath = function (value, lineWidth, old, force, translatedValue) {
            // copy paste handling of x value and sane value threshold
            translatedValue = Math.min(Math.max(-1e5, translatedValue), 1e5);
            x1 = x2 = Math.round(translatedValue + this.transB);

            // max displayed value of your top y-axis
            y1 = this.chart.yAxis[0].toPixels(this.chart.yAxis[0].max);
            // min displayed value of your bottom y-axis
            y2 = this.chart.yAxis[1].toPixels(this.chart.yAxis[1].min);

            return this.chart.renderer.crispLine(
                ['M', x1, y1, 'L', x2, y2],
                lineWidth || 1
            );
        };
        proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        H.Axis.prototype.getPlotLinePath = old_function;
    });
}(Highcharts));
```

Note that this approach is very much directly addressing your problem by extending `Axis.drawCrosshair`, and within that extension rewriting the `Axis.getPlotLinePath` function to alter the path given for the crosshair. It does also not address crosshairs along the y-axis. Still, this could probably be solved in a similar way. It should be thoroughly tested for artifacts.

Answer (score 1):

The length of the the crosshair is the same as xAxis height, so depending on the result you want to achieve set right xAxis height. Axis offset does not affect to the crosshair.

```
xAxis: {
    crosshair: true,
    height: 343, //  yAxis[1].top - yAxis[0].top + yAxis[1].height
    offset: -174
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/w5c82ja9/